# Create custom, iOS 6 like, App Store TabBar (image included)

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm working on an app originally developed by another programmer. My job is to make the interface more appealing. One really effective way I've found is to customize the tab bar. I've become very fond of iOS 6's App Store for iPad. I was wondering what would be the best way to recreate this (for iPad)? Any help would be greatly appreciated guys!

[image]

The app relies heavily on the UITabBar, so I'm trying my best not to change this model. I've checked out TBTabBar, but currently it only supports the iPhone.

Comment: This looks like a UITabBarController with a segmented control in the navigation bar.  This question is pretty broad, so a broad answer is the best you can hope for I think.

Comment: Thanks but I know what the navigation bar is comprised out, what I was saying is I want to recreate the UITabBar shown above. I.e. how should I subclass, categorize, and is there another approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found some customisation [here](http://kurrytran.blogspot.ro/2011/10/ios-5-tutorial-creating-custom-tab-bar.html)  and [here](http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/). I don't know if it is working on iPad too, but I hope it helps to get a direction.

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Enjoy your weekend!